# Significance difference test between two simple slopes within three level categorical predictor

Tags: interaction, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

I've come across related forums, but can't seem to fit them to my problem --  I have significant interaction in a multi-level framework between a three-level categorical predictor (condition assignment - one of which is a control condition and the other two experimental conditions) and a two-level categorical predictor. I would like to compare the simple slopes of the two experimental conditions, while ignoring the control. I've already run three separate simple slopes tests on each of the three conditions to see if they significantly differed from zero using the following formula (repeated three times), where each condition was dummy-coded while acting as the reference group for its particular simple slopes test:

```
omnibus.cc <- lmer(trust~(1+group|participant) + DC_cc1*group + DC_cc2*group, 
data=study2_dummycodes_simp.effects)
```

Where I'm running into trouble though is coming up with the most appropriate coding system and also which significance test to use to compare the two simple slopes of my experimental conditions, as mentioned above.

Any help would be much appreciated.